# Manipulating string variables in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In my JMeter plan, I have a variable that is the result of an LDAP request and then an Xpath Extractor.

This variable ("extractedTimestamps") has 4 timestamp strings (e.g., "20181022012345-4"), each separated by ", ", e.g:

```
20181022012341-4, 20181022012342-4, 20181022012343-4, 20181022012345-4
```

In my test plan, I create a new variable, "newTimestamp", in a UDF using:

```
${__time(yyyyMMddhhmmssX)}
```

So for example, that will create the new timestamp string in the "newTimestamp" var:

```
20181023012323-4
```

I need to (a) remove the first timestamp string from "extractedTimestamps" var and then (b) concatenate the value in the "newTimestamp" var, with a comma separator and put the resulting string in a new variable, "combinedNewTimestamp".

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a *One-Liner* in [JSR223 Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) script:

```
vars.put("extractedTimestamps", vars.get("newTimestamp") + vars.get("oldTimestamp").substring(vars.get("newTimestamp").length()));
```

This can also be inside other component inside [__groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function

> ```
> ${__groovy(vars.get("myVar").substring(0\,2))}
> ```
>
> If var's value is JMeter, it will return JM as it runs String.substring(0,2). Note that , has been escaped to \,